# state several objects within tween trough as3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, tween

```
            myTween = new Tween(t1, "alpha",None.easeNone,1,0,2,true);
```

how can i change t1 for 5 objects without adding more lines?

also is there way to use array like myobjects[a] = "object1", myobject[b] = "object2" ... etc.
so i can just check for active object with

```
event.target
```

and substract this one from array and make this tweet apply to all except one thats clicked.

Comment: If you want to use an associative array, then use the `Dictionary` class.Also why don't you just use a for loop that iterates from one display object to another, adding a tween to each one.

Answer (score 1):

By far the best Tween framework is greensock. To do what you are asking, simply do the following:

```
TweenMax.allTo(myObjects, 1, {alpha:2, ease:None.easeNone});
```

http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/TweenMax.html#allTo%28%29

You'll have to download the framework, which is very lightweight. Greensock promote themselves on their ultra small size.

As for the second question, simply do this

```
myObjects.forEach(function(item:*, i:int, a:Array):void {
    if(item != event.target) {
        // do stuff for tweet
        trace(item); // outputs each item except event.target
    }
});
```